# AOT is mising from Dynamics AX 2012 installation

Tags: installation, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I've installed successfully beta version of Dynamics ax 2012, i tried using business user, developer and administration but in the workspace i was not able to find AOT .
I synchronize table, put license twice and again compile and synchronize but  couldn't find AOT.
I would be thankful if anybody help me regarding installation scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The AOT can be found in the development workspace. 
To open the development workspace, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. 
To open the AOT, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, after installing AX2012 R2 and providing the licence information I could not open the AOT. This was the 3rd time I was installing AX2012 to test our upgrade process, every other time this worked fine and this was on the same server with the same user permissions. The only difference was that I had installed the binary part of CU7 since the last time it worked. So I uninstalled all AX components, cache files, temp files left behind and registry entries and reinstalled without CU7 and it is working fine now. From my testing this does not work for me with CU7 so we will be installing CU7 after out upgrade has been completed.